# Como sair de um loop dentro de outro através de uma função no python?

Tags: python, loop

Oi, estou confuso e não estou conseguindo deixar meu código do jeito ideal.
O que preciso, é de sair de todos os loops através da função `ask_continue()`
depois de o usuário responder `n` no input sem sair do programa, temporariamente, coloquei `exit()` só pra no mínimo rodar.
aqui está o código:

```
print('Olá, seja bem vindo!')
programa = 0
while programa == 0:



def ask_continue():
    ask = str(input("Deseja repetir a operação? (Y/N): "))
    if ask.lower() == 'y':
        program = 0
    elif ask.lower() == 'n':
        programa =+ 1
        exit()


x = 0
while x == 0:
    try:
        a = float(input("Informe a variável 'a': "))
        b = float(input("Informe a variável 'b': "))
        campo_de_saída = a*b-a+b
        print("O campo de saída é {}".format(campo_de_saída))
        ask_continue()
    except:
        print("Valor inválido, tente novamente.")
        x = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso de sair de loops aninhados realmente é um problema de programação que dura gerações.

O comando `break`, como você deve saber, sai de um único `for` ou `while`, e tem que estar diretamente dentro desse `for` ou `while`- não poderia estar dentro de uma função chamada para esse fim.

Então, se o break fosse a única coisa existente, a única forma de resolver seria essa:

```
def funcao_que_resolve_se_sai():
    ...
    return sair_ou_nao

def funcao_principal():
    sair = False
    for laco1 in coisas1:
       for laco2 in coisas2:
           ...
           sair = funcao_que_resolve_se_sai()
           if sair:
                break
       if sair:
           break
```

Ou seja: você teria que guardar a decisão de sair dentro de uma variável, 
e ter um `if` com um  `break` em cada laço.

Em Python, e outras linguagens de alto-nível que tem o recurso de "exceções", isso se resolve com o uso das mesmas.

Mas "exceção não é só quando acontece um erro?" - não necessariamente - 
uma exceççao pode ser causada deliberadamente, com o comando `raise`, 
justamente com o intuíto de mandar um sinal
que consiga escapar da ordem normal de execução.

O ideal é criar uma exceção personalizada, para diferencia-la,
mesmo que só de forma semântica, de uma exceção real, causada por um
problema na execução. Mas para manter o exemplo simples, vou usar
o `RuntimeError` mesmo:

```
def funcao_que_resolve_se_sai():
    ...
    if sair_ou_nao:
        raise RuntimeError()


def funcao_principal():
    try:
       for laco1 in coisas1:
          for laco2 in coisas2:
           ...
           funcao_que_resolve_se_sai()
     except RuntimeError:
         pass

funcao_principal()
```

Então veja como ficou- quando a exceção "RuntimeError" é causada pelo comando `raise` dentro da função chamada, o programa vai pular direto para
a próxima cláusula `except` que pegar essa exceção. Se a claúsula estiver depois dos loops que queremos deixar, ele sai de todos os loops.

Agora note uma cois a **importante**: eu coloco o nome da função específica no `except`. No seu código, você coloca `except` sem nada, dentro do seus laços - isso é uma prática muito ruim, já que o `except` sem nada pega *todos* os tipos de erro - inclusive erros que vocẽ não está esperando, e mais ainda, inclusive qualquer erro personalizado que você queria usar para o controle do fluxo do programa.

Por isso é muito, **muito mesmo**  importante sempre colocar exceções específicas quando usar o Excecept. No caso do seu código, você usa o except para tratar valores não numéricos que o usuário digita. O erro lançado nesse caso é o `ValueError`. Então seu programa, na parte interna dos laços, tem que capturar *só* o ValueError!

Essa técnica de exceções personalizadas é interessnte, por que não importa quantos loops, e quantas funções são chamadas uma dentro da outra (isso é - vamos dizer que a `funcao_que_resolve_se_sai` chamasse ainda uma outra função) - quando a exceção é lançada, o programa sai das funções e dos laços todos, até o Except.

Isso dá um controle muito maior do que chamar `exit`, porque depois do Except, você continua executando o programa na próxima linha, normalmente. (o comando `pass` dentro do Except não faz nada, só deixa o bloco com a sintaxe válida, por que ele não pode ser vazio)

Isso é usado em qualquer sistema grande em Python - por exemplo, em sistemas Web, os frameworks sempre chamam as funções do seu sistema dentro de uma cláusula "try--except" apropriada - se o seu código gerar qualquer erro, o `except` para todo o seu código, e gera uma página HTML com o código de erro apropriado - e, o servidor continua rodando normalmente, esperando outras requisições.

Por fim, a forma de personalizar uma exceção também é bem simples - é só criar uma subclasse, que pode ser vazia, de `Exception`:

```
class SairDosLacos(Exception):
    pass

def funcao_que_resolve_se_sai():
    ...
    if sair_ou_nao:
        raise SairDosLacos()


def funcao_principal():
    try:
       for laco1 in coisas1:
           for laco2 in coisas2:
              numero_ok = False
              while not numero_ok:
                  try:
                      a  = int(input("digite um número"))
                  except ValueError:
                      print("número inválido, tente de novo - ")
                  else:
                      numero_ok = True
               # codigo usando o número digitado:
               ...
               funcao_que_resolve_se_sai()
     except SairDosLacos:
         pass
funcao_principal()
```

(note aqui o uso  do `else` para o  `try/except/else` - o bloco `else` do comando `try` só é executado se não aconteceu nenhuma exceção - nesse caso, se o número for válido)

---

Há um outra forma sem uso de exceções, que não dá pra usar no seu caso, por que você não colocou seus laços principais do programa dentro de uma função - acostume-se a sempre fazer isso.

Mas além de uma exceção com o comando raise, um outro comando que sai de qualquer número de loops é o `return` - ele encerra a função atual imediatamente, e o controle volta para a função que chamou a atual.

Se dentro da função você não vai fazer mais nada depois dos laços (e está dentro de uma função), é só por um return.

O seu código ficaria assim:

```
print('Olá, seja bem vindo!')
programa = 0
while programa == 0:



def ask_continue():
    ask = str(input("Deseja repetir a operação? (Y/N): "))
    if ask.lower() == 'y':
        program = 0
        return True
    elif ask.lower() == 'n':
        programa =+ 1
        return False


def principal():
    x = 0
    while x == 0:
        try:
            a = float(input("Informe a variável 'a': "))
            b = float(input("Informe a variável 'b': "))
            campo_de_saída = a*b-a+b
            print("O campo de saída é {}".format(campo_de_saída))
            if not ask_continue():
                 return
        except:
            print("Valor inválido, tente novamente.")
            x = 0
```

---

Linguagens que não tem o mecanismo de exceções, como o C, para sair de vários laços as vezes tem o comando `goto` - ele pode fazer a execução do programa saltar incondicionalmente para uma linha específica dentro da mesma função.

A literatura de programação execra o `goto` de forma que sua menção causa "medo" em muitos profissionais experientes - por que era a única forma de modelar laços e funções antes de linguagens que tinham funções como as conhecemos hoje - só que por conta de sua flexibilidade extra, um programa poderia ficar realmente difícil de se acompanhar ou entender.

Bem usado, no entanto, ele é a forma convencional de sair de laços - um `if` no laço mais interno pode conter um `goto` para um ponto fora de todos os laços. 
Reitero que `goto` não existe em Python - existe em `C`, e é a forma recomendada, por exemplo, de codificar o tratamento de erros se vocẽ está criando uma função em C que vai interagir, e ser chamada a partir de código Python.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi o que você quer fazer realmente, pois pelo que vi vc fez uma função que simplesmente ela não sai do loop...
mas vou tentar resolver veja abaixo se é isso que você quer, eu tirei estas condicionais que deixavam o loop infinito, pois para continuar o programa basta satisfazer a pergunta com y, mas fica claro que com o exit() o programa sai por completo, segue:

```
class Program():
def __init__(self):
    self.ask_continue()

def ask_continue(self):

    ask = 'y'
    while ask.lower() == 'y':

        a = float(input("Informe a variável 'a': "))
        b = float(input("Informe a variável 'b': "))
        campo_de_saída = a*b-a+b
        print("O campo de saída é {}".format(campo_de_saída))
        ask = str(input("Deseja repetir a operação? (Y/N): "))
        if ask.lower() == 'n':
            programa =+ 1
            exit()







if __name__ == "__main__":
     Program()
```